# How to compress a list of dates into ranges in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I have a list of dates like this:

2nd August 1994, 31st October 1994, 6th December 1994, 7th December 1994, 8th December 1994, 4th February 1997, 5th February 1997, 6th February 1997, 7th February 1997, 8th February 1997, 9th February 1997, 10th February 1997, 11th February 1997, 12th February 1997, 13th February 1997, 14th February 1997, 15th February 1997, 16th February 1997, 17th February 1997, 18th February 1997, 19th February 1997, 20th February 1997, 21st February 1997, 22nd February 1997, 23rd February 1997, 24th February 1997, 25th February 1997, 26th February 1997, 27th February 1997, 28th February 1997 and 17th June 1997

I would like to compress this list into something more readable to the user like this:

2nd August 1994, 31st October 1994, 6th-8th December 1994, 4th-28th February 1997 and 17th June 1997

The dates are already stored in a javascript array in epochseconds.  I have no idea where to start doing this.  I am already using moment.js if that helps.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should first group each month dates then get lowest and highest date of that month and show as you want

Comment: What is the actual list you have? You are showing a list of strings, but you say it's in "epochseconds".  Do you mean you have an array of [Unix Timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)?  If so, you also need to consider [time zones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timezone), because the UTC date may not be the same as the local date, and the local date could change depending on which time zone you are viewing it in.  Do you want this to be in the *local time zone* of the person viewing the results?

Comment: Also, please recognize that StackOverflow is not really meant to be a place where you list your requirements and expect a working solution.  It's a question and answer site, and the best questions and answers are those that are reusable by many individuals - not just you.  Please try to ask your question in a way that is more useful, and show what code you've already tried.  If you haven't tried *anything* yet, then you haven't done enough research to ask the question and you'll likely get downvoted. Please read about [asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in the help center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:
This is not the best way to do it but it will work for you

```
   var dates = ["2nd August 1994", "31st October 1994", "6th December 1994", "7th December 1994", "8th December 1994", "4th February 1997", "5th February 1997", "6th February 1997", "7th February 1997", "8th February 1997", "9th February 1997", "10th February 1997", "11th February 1997", "12th February 1997", "13th February 1997", "14th February 1997", "15th February 1997", "16th February 1997", "17th February 1997", "18th February 1997", "19th February 1997", "20th February 1997", "21st February 1997", "22nd February 1997", "23rd February 1997", "24th February 1997", "25th February 1997", "26th February 1997", "27th February 1997", "28th February 1997", "17th June 1997"];

var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
getDatesInSortedOrder(dates);
function getDatesInSortedOrder(dates){
  //alert($('#test').html());
  var new_dates = [];
  var group_of_dates = {};
  $.each(dates, function( index, value ) {
    var new_val = value.split(" ");
    var dt = new Date(new_val[2], months.indexOf(new_val[1]), new_val[0].slice(0, new_val[0].length - 2))
    new_dates.push(dt)
  });

  $.each(new_dates, function( index, date ) {
    var day = date.getDate(), month = date.getMonth(), year = date.getFullYear();
    date_group = month + "_" + year
    if(group_of_dates[date_group] == undefined){
      group_of_dates[date_group] = [date];
    } else {
      var temp = group_of_dates[date_group];
      temp.push(date)
      group_of_dates[date_group] = temp;
    }
    });
  var sorted_dates = {};

  for (var key in group_of_dates) {
    sorted_dates[key] = sortDate(group_of_dates[key])
  }

  console.log(sorted_dates)
  var finalArray = [];
  for (var key in sorted_dates) {
    var dates_array = sorted_dates[key];
    if (dates_array.length > 1){
      var readableDate = dates_array[0].getDate() + "-" + dates_array[dates_array.length - 1].getDate() + " " + months[dates_array[0].getMonth()]  + " " + dates_array[0].getFullYear();
      finalArray.push(readableDate)
    } else {
      var readableDate = dates_array[0].getDate() + " " + months[dates_array[0].getMonth()]  +" " +  dates_array[0].getFullYear();
      finalArray.push(readableDate)
    }
  }

  alert(finalArray.join(", "))
}


function sortDate(dates){
   new_dates  = dates.sort(function(a,b){
      if (a > b) return 1;
      if (a < b) return -1;
      return 0;
  });
  return new_dates;
}
```

[Jsfiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/n0v0np1d/)

Comment: This looks great!  I am just trying to work out how it actually works.  I then just have to add on the st/nd/rd/th onto the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea, which you can convert to code. Have 2 variables `startDate` and `endDate` without assigning any value yet. Put the 1st date in `startDate` and `endDate`. Starting from the 2nd date, get the difference in number of days between current date and `endDate`. If difference is 1 store the current value in `endDate`. Keep doing this until you reach a difference of more than 1 day. At that instant, print the values of `startDate` and `endDate`, and make them undefined again. Do this until you are done with all dates.